# Problem regarding differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am looking for the solution of the following problem,

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a twice differentiable function with $f(0) =2, f^{\prime}(0)=2$ and $f(1)=1.$  Then there is $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)f^{\prime}(x)+f^{\prime \prime}(x)=0.$

I think we have to use mean value theorem for the problem. But I can't figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated .

Thank you.

Comment: i think we need the value of $f'(1)$ also

Comment: Where did you get the problem from?